# How can I sum the earliest and the most record in a group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table with the `uid`, `date`, and the `value`.

I want to group by uid, and get the different between the earliest found `value` and the most recent `value`. How can I do this in ActiveRecord or just SQL?

Example Data:

```
UID   DATE        VALUE
------------------------------
a    | 2016-10-01 | 5
a    | 2016-8-01 | 10
a    | 2016-12-01 | 15
b    | 2016-10-01 | 5
b    | 2016-8-01 | 10
c    | 2016-12-01 | 15
```

Desired Result

```
UID   DELTA (absolute value)     
------------------------------
a    | 5
b    | 5
c    | 15
```

Comment: Dear, Add a data set and a desired result set. You have written 350 questions, please write better this ;)

Comment: i think  Desired Result  for a = 10 ?

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale It's earliest not least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select uid, abs(max(latest) - max(first)) diff
from
(select uid,
  case when (row_number() over 
           (partition by uid order by date asc)) = 1 
           then value end first,
  case when (row_number() over 
           (partition by uid order by date desc)) = 1 
           then value end latest
from table
) t
group by uid;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not experienced with activerecord, but in plain SQL you can use the `row_number` window function to find the first and last records. E.g.:

```
WITH first_and_last AS (
    SELECT uid, 
           value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY date ASC) as r_asc
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY date DESC) as r_desc
    FROM   mytable)
SELECT a.uid, a.value - b.value
FROM   first_and_last a
JOIN   first_and_last b ON a.uid = b.uid AND a.r_desc = 1 AND b.r_asc = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use window functions before aggregation, then use `first_value()` and/or `last_value()`:

```
select uid, abs(max(value_first) - max(value_last)) as diff
from (select uid,
             first_value(value) over (partition by uid order by date asc) as value_first,
             first_value(value) over (partition by uid order by date desc) as value_last
      from table
     ) t
group by uid;
```

You can also do this without a subquery at all, if you want to use array aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  t(i,d,v) as (
    values
      ('a'::text, '2016-10-01'::date, 5::int),
      ('a', '2016-08-01', 10),
      ('a', '2016-12-01', 15),
      ('b', '2016-10-01', 5),
      ('b', '2016-08-01', 10),
      ('c', '2016-12-01', 15)),
  e as (
    select distinct on (i) * from t order by i, d),
  l as (
    select distinct on (i) * from t order by i, d desc)
select
  e.i,
  abs(e.v - case when e.d=l.d then 0 else l.v end) as diff
from
  e join l using(i);
```

The `case` in the final query needed to handle the cases like `c` `uid` where only one row in the row set (of course it does not handle the cases with several rows with same dates, so you can use 'id' if it present).

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        select distinct a.UID,
        -- ,a."VALUE",b."VALUE",
        abs(coalesce (a."VALUE",0)-coalesce(b."VALUE",0)) 
        AS "DELTA (absolute value)"
        from
        (select * from 
        (select UID,"VALUE",ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by uid order by rnk desc ) as rnk from 
        (
        select UID,"VALUE", date,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by uid order by  (select 1 ) )as rnk
        from  edata
        )a  )a where rnk='1' )a
        left join 
        ( select * FROM 
        (select UID,"VALUE",ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by uid order by rnk desc ) as rnk from 
        (
        select UID,"VALUE", date,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by uid order by  (select 1 ) )as rnk
        from  edata
        )
        b )b  where    b.rnk=2 )B
        on a.uid=b.uid ORDER BY UID
```

Also Try postgresql [Demo](http://rextester.com/OMNW68496) Here.

Above code is working fine for SQL server and postgresql.

> Output :

[image]